# Where can I find cars that are already modded?

Tags: xbox-one, grand-theft-auto-online

While driving around Los Santos, I stumbled across a Rat Rod at a gas station. Something on it looked different so I hopped in and drove it back to my apartment. To my amazement, when I took it to a mod shop, I saw that it already had a bunch of mods done to it.

**Are there other cars in GTA Online that are already pre-modded? If so, where can I find them?**

Not sure if it matters any, but I am playing on Xbox One.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The only two places where I've found that modded cars consistently appear are the purple circles. One is a garage up the ally where you have a mission with the Photographer and Franklin at one point. The other is the mod shop where you fix Michel's car, though the second one is much less common to have cars.

Comment: Are you finding these in the story mode or online? Just wondering since you mention Franklin and Michael.

Comment: I was never in need of a moded car in online, as my Kuruma is more than enough for me. So I've only seen these in Story Mode, but I bet they will be there in Online too.

Comment: Just now I noticed you're talking about Gta online. Still give these spots a try, go around them few times. Also the hood around the mod shop in the city centre somtimes spawns a moded car.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy moded cars from Benny's Original Motor Works.

Check their page in the GTA Webbrowser.

You can buy the unmoded car from them and bring that car to them. There you you will find the option to turn the car to their moded Version. That includes modification that are not available othewise. That obviously comes with a rather high cost.